# Spark Dataframe - How to get a particular field from a struct type column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with a structure like this:

```
root
 |-- npaDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- additionalInformation: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaStatus: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- npaHeaderData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaNumber: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaDownloadDate: string (nullable = true)     
 |    |-- npaDownloadTime: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to retrieve all `npaNumber` from all the rows in the dataframe.

My approach was to iterate over all rows in the data frame to extract for each one the value stored in the column `npaHeaderData`, in the field `npaNumber`. So I code the following lines:

```
parquetFileDF.foreach { newRow =>  

  //To retrieve the second column
  val column = newRow.get(1)

  //The following line is not allowed
  //val npaNumber= column.getAs[String]("npaNumber")  

  println(column)

}
```

The content of column printed in each iteration looks like:

> [207400956,27FEB17,09.30.00]

But `column` is of type Any and I am not able extract any of its fields. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong or what approach should I follow instead of this?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to get a dataframe with one column from a multi-column dataframe, is that the point?

Comment: @MehdiBenHamida I need to retrieve one field from a column in the first step of my algorithm, since I will use that value as a reference for future opperations. So I will need to keep all columns. However for this step, you are right I could select just my second column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are looking to extract only `npaNumber` then you can do

```
parquetFileDF.select($"npaHeaderData.npaNumber".as("npaNumber"))
```

you should have a `dataframe` with `npaNumber` column only.

Comment: I will try that. Later I will need the other columns as well, but as a first step this will works. Thanks!

Comment: Just a comment, I think you both forgot the $"npaHeaderData.npaNumber". At least my IDE was complaining because of that

Answer (score 1):

you can call `select()` on dataframe which will give you a new dataframe with only specified column

```
var newDataFrame = dataFrame.select(dataFrame("npaHeaderData.npaNumber").as("npaNumber"))
```

Comment: is it different than my answer?

Comment: both are same, might be both were answering in parallel

Comment: yup, @RameshMaharjan thanks for pointing out, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below , which will avoid the [] ,while reading data from a data frame.

**ids[DataFrame]: {id, name}**

```
val idRDDs = ids.rdd.map(x => x.getAs[String](0))
for(id <- idRDDs){
     id.map(x => println(x))
 }
```

The above way will solve your issues.